# Redirect .history output on bash execution

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a way to redirect the output of .history when a command was executed.

Example:

command
- > tail -1 .history >> somefile

Basically I want to track the bash history of the users at a particular point in time.I don't have root access to the system, I'm doing it so that I can collect data from the users.

Is there some function that can be overridden to accommodate this (in .bashrc for example) ?

The only thing that I know of is 'builtin' to override the original function, but not everything is builtin so this won't work in my case.

Comment: Am I right to assume that your ultimate goal is to have a protocol that shows every command that was entered by a user and when it was issued?

Comment: You are correct @Steffen Winkler.

Comment: History isn't suitable for the task as it can easily be turned off. You need something like [Linux auditing](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @phd.As I said I don't have root access so I can't install anything.The good news is I came up with a workaround to my problem.It required much more work but it did the job.